# Degraded Java application performance in production

Tags: java, performance

We have a Java application running in production. We are observing degraded application performance in prod vs non-prod environments. Mainly, we have observed that the same operation is taking much longer in production. Are there any pointers as to suggest what might be the potential cause for this?

I observed that the CPU and memory utilisation of machines in prod is quite high.

If high CPU/Memory util is the cause for degradation, can you suggest ways to confirm that? Since this is prod environment, it would not be possible to attach a profiler to the application.

I am very new to this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: External possibility: virus scanner (factor files)?

Comment: [*Java Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) can be used in production.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.